# passing object to the webservice

Tags: javascript, java

I am wondering if the following is possible:

1) I have a Javascript object of an HTML form something like [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7dohbytj/2/).

```
<form >
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
    </form>
<div id="submitParagraphID">
    <img src="myImage.png" alt="Success" /> Thank you for submitting your request.
</div>
<div class="row"style="margin-top: 15px;" >
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="downloadSetsButtonDiv">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitUsingjQuery()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

function submitUsingjQuery(){  
            $("#submitParagraphID").show("fast");
            console.log("Is console log printing?");
            var formdata = $("form").serializeArray();
            alert(JSON.stringify(formdata));
}
```

2) I plan on sending this object via Ajax call to a JAX-RS web service which is using Resteasy. And within this webservice, I will be calling a stored procedure which will be accepting this javascript object somehow. The reason I am following this passing along javascript object approach from the web interface to a stored procedure via java webservice is to 
accomodate if there are any future changes in the parameters.

3) Is it possible to achieve the same? Any example I could refer for this?

Comment: I don't know about Resteasy or JAX-RS, but does the web service requires authentication?

Comment: No, it does not require authentication. My web related stuff and JBOSS are on the same RHEL server. So I would just have to make a web service call to the Java web service.

Comment: It this case it should work. However if there are future changes, you could have to change both the form and the web service.